# Атрибут data и его значение

Tags: jquery

При клике на checkbox нужно скрыть все элементы с атрибутом data-hidden="true".

Я написал такой код: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhsUQ/)

Мой код не работает, объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hidden = $("span[data-hidden='true']");
```

Comment: о Боже... Мне нужно отдохнуть.  Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: btw, если вам не принципиален data-атрибут, несущий дополнительные смыслы, то используйте что-то другое, например <span hi-de> и $('span[hi-de]')

Comment: @kolpak, такой вариант будет работать во всех браузерах?  я что-то впервые вижу такое :(

Comment: должен работать

Comment: @Maqsood, этот синтаксис существует еще со времен [css 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), найти брайзер, не поддерживающий эту спеку, будет довольно серьещной проблемой.